# $_POST: вложенный массив

Tags: post, php, массивы

Смотрю код, а там такой вот пример

```
$_POST['text']['text']
```

Как это возможно, кто может подсказать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<form action="" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="text[a]" value="a">
 <input type="text" name="text[b]" value="b">
 <input type="text" name="text[]" value="c">
 <input type="text" name="text[]" value="d">
 <input type="submit">
</form>

<pre><?php print_r( $_POST ); ?></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```
<input name="text[text]" ... >
```